# MySQL server has gone away, max_allowed_packet does nothing

Tags: php, mysql

I upgraded my PHP to 5.4 on CentOS 6, Parallels Plesk Apache. Everything was fine until I tried to edit a menu link. I got this message:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has
>   gone away

I found the MySQL Configuration file my.cnf and added this line just below [mysql]:

```
max_allowed_packet=500M
```

However this **DOES NOT WORK**. The file never had that line on the old PHP setup and does not have it in the new one. Perhaps there is another reason why the MySQL server has gone away for Drupal?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you restarted the mysql server afterwards?

Comment: There could be any number of reasons you are getting that error.  See the official ducs at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/gone-away.html

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running? If you have console access, run `mysql --version`